# Java regex to match 2 special charater followed by not known number of digits

Tags: java, regex, substring

**Input** may be like

Hi how are you $#85865865 ? what is the day there .

**output**:

Hi how are you ? what is the day there .

```
public class remochar {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String input = "Hi how are you ? hello  &#4567 ghsgsgsf ";
        String regx = "&#";

        char[] ca = regx.toCharArray();
        for (char c : ca) {
            input = input.replace("&#", "");
        }

        System.out.println(input);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what have you tried so far? Could you show us some of your code?

Comment: Very basic task, just read *any* regex tutorial and get it working within the next hour all by yourself.

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* **must** include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]).

Comment: Danke understand . I am learning Java  and I am not just passing my assignment over here  , new to oops . not to IT ..   every one have their own timeline ...

Answer (score 0):

You are welcome:

```
\&#[0-9]+
```

You can use, for example, this online resource to test your regexes: https://regex101.com/. It also explains how regexes work. In this case:

> \&#[0-9]+
>
> "\&" matches the character "$" literally (case sensitive)
>
> "#" matches the character "#" literally (case sensitive)
>
> Match a single character present in the list below [0-9]+
>
> - "+" Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) 0-9 a single character in
> - the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57) (case sensitive)

Comment: `\#` can be replaced with just `#`.

Comment: Yes, it can. Thanks for the addition!

Comment: Can you add a small explanation of the regex inside the answer? This will greatly help readers.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class remochar {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Sample Input and Output :");
        Scanner Iname = new Scanner(System.in);    

        String input = Iname.nextLine();
        String inp = input;

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("&#+[0-9]");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inp);
        if(matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("yes");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested your regex against `$#85865865`? According to [https://regex101.com/](https://regex101.com/) it doesn't work. Probably, use this `\$#[0-9]+`

Comment: @sergei  my requirement is for &# not $#  ...  by mistake typo i posted  $# initially

Comment: But `&#+[0-9]` will not going to work anyway. So, do you want regex for such string `&#85865865`? Actually, have you found the answer to your question? I've updated my answer with "&".

Comment: it worked if the sentence has that particular &# followed by numbers , it passed the condition .